# Convert custom QPalette to a StyleSheet

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

I am using a custom `QPalette` that resides as its own code. I use the palette by: `self.setPalette(self.customPalette())`. I have come to learn about the shortcomings of palettes the hard way. I need to convert the look/style/feel into a CSS stylesheet. Is this possible, and what is the best way?

Comment: The unfortunate part is that Designer almost encourages the palette scheme by making it so easy to change colors. I need a way to take what designer provides and turn it into a stylesheet

Comment: Have a look at http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/49064-QPalette-and-stylesheet and http://agateau.com/2008/qt-stylesheets-and-qpalette/